# Run time error in perl

Tags: perl, par

I have made a standalone exe file by packaging a perl file using PAR::Packager.

The file works perfectly in my system, but it throws an error. if i used it in another system which have windows xp as OS.

```
The locale codeset (cp936) isn't one that perl can decode,Stopped at Encode/Locale.pm line 94
Compliation failed in require at LWP/UserAgent.pm line 1000
```

Please give some suggestion.Thanks

Update :
the files i have included in the script is

```
use Encode::Byte;
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use utf8;
```

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=920335

Comment: @mpapec Thanks , but i have already included the file in my script.

Comment: what about `Encode::Alias Encode::Config`?

Comment: what about `Encode::CN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the following line in your code:

```
use Encode::CN;
```

As you can see in [Encode::Byte documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/ext/Encode/lib/Encode/Supported.pod#Encode%3a%3aByte_--_Extended_ASCII), **cp936** it is not included. But it is listed in [Encode::CN docs](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/ext/Encode/lib/Encode/Supported.pod#CJK%3a_Chinese,_Japanese,_Korean_%28Multibyte%29).

Adding both packages (Encode::Byte and Encode::CN should solve your problem).